# Is there a way to fix mark seams "border" which are showing in render?

Tags: texturing, uv

I did uv-map and in render there are these kind of border in places where I mark seams.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

https://ibb.co/vY00k9s

Comment: that can be a normal issue. Try Sift+N to recalculate them.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: you should had more information about the mesh. eventually upload it (or a part of it) using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ...and I think this is not a uv seam issue

Comment: I added blend file.

Comment: this is probably due to the normal map but the blend file does not include "bump to" texture...

Comment: I upload it. Sorry I'm not used to this kind of stuff.

Comment: well... can only say that disconnection normal map solves the seam. But hard to say the diff in the normal map texture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use normal map in a shader you have to change the color space to "Non-Color". If you change the texture file you have to do it again.
[image]

Comment: This is it. Thank you.